# List all active Configuration for Config Admin in gogo shell

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, gogo-shell

I would like to show on screen the `Configuration` list returned by `org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin.listConfigurations` method via gogo shell. I tried with the following:

```
g! _sref = $.context getServiceReference "org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin"
g! _srv = $.context getService $_sref
g! $_srv listConfigurations
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
gogo: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce listconfigurations() to any of [(String)]
```

What is the right syntax here? Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listConfigurations` method takes a String parameter, which is a filter. If you just want an unfiltered list, then you can pass `null`, e.g.:

```
$_srv listConfigurations null
```

This returns an array of Configuration objects, which you will probably want to iterate over with the `each` command.

However this kind of thing quickly gets too complex for Gogo scripting. For example you're not releasing the service reference with `ungetService` anywhere. It's probably better to build a reusable Gogo command in Java as a Declarative Services component.

Comment: So it was enough to write null at the end. Thank you. By the way, the complete each command I used is the following: `_out = $_srv listConfigurations null` / `each [ $_out ] { echo $it }`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a lot easier to use the following shell commands to achieve that:

https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/net.luminis.cmc

Which has, amongst other things, a command called:

```
cm list
```